# WPF RibbonSplitButton doesn't fire MouseDown or MouseLeftButtonDown event

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm using a RibbonSplitButton in my application with three sub item.
When I keep clicked the button I start a procedure that I stop when the button is released. The problem is the RibbonSplitButton doesn't fires any events (with the event of the click exception). The same work should be done also by RibbonMenuItem.
This is my code:
**XAML**

```
<ribbon:RibbonSplitButton LargeImageSource="images/move.png"
                      Label="Muovi"
                      //incriminated methods
                      MouseLeftButtonDown="Movimento_StartContinuous"
                      MouseDown="Movimento_StartContinuous"
                      MouseLeftButtonUp="Movimento_StopContinuous"
                      TouchUp="Movimento_StopContinuous"
                      TouchDown="Movimento_StartContinuous"
                      //yeah, this work well
                      Click="Movimento_StartContinuous">
    <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Veloce"
                           //incriminated methods
                           MouseLeftButtonDown="Movimento_StartContinuous_Veloce"
                           MouseLeftButtonUp="Movimento_StopContinuous" />
    <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Normale"/>
    <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Lento"/>
</ribbon:RibbonSplitButton>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Movimento_StartContinuous(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    //never go here
    e.Handled = true;
}
private void Movimento_StartContinuous(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e) {
    //never go here
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topmost elements are probably *swallow* these events (you're swallowing them too by setting `e.Handled` to `true`, but these handlers are never invoked as you say.). You can try handling the preview events instead (`PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, `PreviewTouchDown`).

Note: Not every event has a preview version. Most of input related events have a preview version, but for example the `Click` event doesn't.

Comment: Thank you Eldar! I use the e.Handled to prevent the double calling to the function when I click a sub item. I've try your solution but if the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown works great on the RibbonSplitButton, the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp fires when I click the RibbonSplitButton arrow because I want click the subitem. In this mode I can't perform any action on the sub item :(

Comment: @ilsergente93 Well, that's a downside of using preview events. These events should be used only if you don't have any other option. Relating to your problem: you can check the `sender` for equality to your `RibbonSplitButton`.

Comment: @ilsergente93 Please, don't forget to mark this as the answer, if it helps you.